# How to convert tuple to byte array in c++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, tuples, byte

I need to write a function to convert tuple to byte array.
The type of tuple may include `int, long, double, std::string, char*`,etc.
The size and type of tuple are arbitrary, such as

```
std:tuple<string, int, double> t1("abc", 1, 1.3);
```

or

```
std:tuple<char*, int, int, float, double, string> t2("abc", 1, 2, 1.3, 1.4, "hello");
```

I want use these tuple as input, and the byte array as return value. What should I do ?

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to serialize and deserialize the tuple?

Comment: Conversion to byte arrays requires serialization and often marshalling.  There is no single serialization format, you have to pick a representation first.

Comment: @BrianCain sure I implied that also

Comment: @BrianCain Actually, I want put all the tuple (as a multi-value-key) values in a byte array, and feed the array and its length to the standard murmur3 algorithm to get the hashing result. So, What can I do ? How to serialize the tuple, thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

There is also the brilliant [C++ API](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c) for [message pack](http://msgpack.org/index.html) which supports tuples natively

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>

#include <msgpack.hpp>

int main() {
    auto t = std::make_tuple("1", 1, 1.0);
    auto buffer = std::stringstream{};

    // easy peezy
    msgpack::pack(buffer, t);
    auto tuple_as_string = buffer.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Boost Serialization for this task together with a small extension for `std::tuple`.  However, it doesn't turn it into a byte array by default, but into something else.  There is also `binary_oarchive`.  Perhaps this fits your needs.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <tuple>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include "serialize_tuple.h" // https://github.com/Sydius/serialize-tuple

int main()
{
  auto t = std::make_tuple(42,3.14,'a');

  std::ofstream ofs("test.dat");
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa << t;
}
```