# Serializing variadic template tuple in C++

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic

I am trying to implement serialize and deserialize methods in the following class.

```
 template <class...T>
    class Collection{
    public:
     //.....

    std::vector<char> serialize();
    std::tuple<T...> deserialize(std::vector<char> & vec);



    private:
    std::tuple<T...> data;
};
```

T could be any built in type like int, long, string, etc. The return type is a byte stream of all elements int the tuple for serialize method and a tuple from the raw data for the deserialize method.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are serializing to string, you can simply use `std::ostringstream`. Otherwise, you'll need a templated binary serializer, which the STL does not provde.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793459/1944004).

Comment: I want to convert each T to its byte representation and put in vector<char>.